# javascript parse template - native way?

Tags: javascript, parsing, templates, native

How can I parse and evaluate a template, from a string, or from a tag:  (which is the same)
 `<script type="template">hello {{person.name}}</script>` ?

```
var person = {name: "foo"}
```

in a way that is **native** to the browser?
So far the only way I've came up with is using `s.replace("{{person.name}}", person.name)` multiple times, but that seems inconvenient and inefficient.

Especially I would like to know how the known libraries (angular, underscore, mustache etc.) do it. i.e, in which javascript functions they use.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are libraries out there, which can do it, however in ES6 its built in, it called **Template_literals**

The syntax is

```
let name = "Bob";
let halloBob = `Hello ${name}`
```

If you are targeting ES5 then you should use some library like

http://handlebarsjs.com/

But there are a lot more then just handlebars, I found this blog post, how you can write your own template library in 20 LOC:

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Javascript-template-engine-in-just-20-line

Comment: I know these libraries, I just wanted to know what is the native (=no library) way to do this. i.e in what way these libraries work with templates, even a general idea

Comment: And I assume all these libraries (angular for example), don't use the new template syntax since it is not widely supported yet. Good to know though.

Comment: @user3599803 alright, if this is answering your question, it would be nice, if you accept it ;)

Comment: nice, but just to know - all these common libraries(angular, underscore etc), simply use regex to parse the templates, and to do the substitutions ?

Comment: I think, this is not related to the initial question and is easy to investigate just by reading the source code, cheers @user3599803

Comment: While the code in the blog post is interesting, the advanced examples will trigger a CSP violation in Chrome.  If you need advanced templating still better off using Handlebars or similar IMO.